# When redirect from page 1 to page 2, shows page 2 loading instead of page 1 loading

Tags: php

We have the following pages:

1. **Page 1**: Controlled by my team, load fast
2. **Page 2**: Controlled by other teams, legacy so load very slow on first landing (let say takes 10 seconds)

Page 1 is sort of an login program, so after login to Page 1, it will redirect to Page 2 automatically.

#### The behavior

1. User goes to Page 1, login (a few ms)
2. User get redirect to Page 2 (Takes 10 seconds)
3. Issue is, on the browser, **it is showing Page 1 loading for 10 seconds**
4. So now, user is going to blame Page 1 loading very slow,

   - since in they perspective, page 1 takes 10 seconds to load Page 2.
5. In reality, the issue is in Page 2, upgrading Page 1 will not help

#### What I want to achieve

- The user browser showing Page 2 load for 10 seconds, instead of showing Page 1 load for long time.
- So, user can correctly judge which page is slow and sent their complain accordingly

#### What I have tried:

1. PHP: Location header
2. Javascript: `location.href='test2.php';`
3. Javascript: `window.location.replace ('test2.php');`

Still, all those method result in the showing of Page 1 loading

I am out of idea, so I am asking in here. Any method using PHP / Javascrpit will do, many thanks!

Comment: redirect in a new tab maybe: `window.open('test2.php', '_blank');` ( but note: it won't work if user's browser blocks popups )

Comment: Oh that's an very interesting approach, let me see if that is feasible in my project. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the idea of opening `test2.php` in a new tab works for you, then I'd suggest a different approach than `window.open`:

```
function openInNewTab(href) {
  Object.assign(document.createElement('a'), {
    target: '_blank',
    href,
  }).click();
}

openInNewTab("test2.php");
```

Comment: While unfortunately I cannot implement this solution due to the UX impact. I accept this because I think this solution is exactly what I was asking for, an interesting alternative angle to my problem. Many thanks!